# Azure Search indexing of Azure Blob Storage: what is the best unique index "key"?

Tags: azure, search, indexing, blob

In order to automatically index Azure Storage blobs with Azure Search, an index need to have one of its fields as a unique "key". Azure docs say: "There can only be one key field in the index. It has to be a string field. This field represents the unique identifier for each document stored with the index."

My question is: what is the best unique key for a blob? It cannot be a blob path or name, since "/" and "." cannot be in the "key" value. Shall I assign a customized property to every blob after I upload it to Azure Storage?

What would be the best way to do it? Is anyone here has experience with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [`link`](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage), you could use `metadata_storage_path` attribute (which represents full blob path and thus unique) as key field. Again based on the documentation, you should use `base64Encode` function to convert that data into Base64 encoded string to avoid invalid characters in the key name field value.

From the documentation link (please see section titled `Defining document keys and field mappings`):

> **metadata_storage_path** - using the full path ensures uniqueness, but
>   the path definitely contains / characters that are invalid in a
>   document key. As above, you have the option of encoding the keys using
>   the base64Encode function.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need.